# Stretch container height depending on background size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, background

I know there were similar questions, but this is slightly different. Just read description)

I have a main container (red) that is stretching depending on screen size. Inside of it there is second container (blue) that has div with fixed height at the top and background picture.

At first I tried using `background: cover` for picture in the background. But at some sizes different parts of background cannot be seen and that's a no no.

So what I'm trying to achieve is for svg background to stretch depending on blue container's width and remain it's ratio. Also, I want second container to change height depending on it's background, so whole svg picture will be always visible.

Is it possible to achieve with only css? If not, then how can I make it using js? I cannot make changes to existing html.
[image: wireframe]

Comment: could you please provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with your code so we can A.) see what you have tried. and B.) see how the html is laid out and see if we can help you without needing to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a minimum width to SVG background to make sure it doesn't become so small that the picture is cut off. As far as the boxes maintaining their ratios you can use percentages for both the width and the height and set them to whatever you want, for example, the width of container2 is 70% of the width of container, and SVG background is 90% of the width of container2.